# From coordinate standard deviation to Standard Distance Deviation

Tags: statistics, euclidean-geometry, variance

How do I get from some standard-deviation/variance of $x$ and $y$ coordinates to Standard Distance Deviation/RMSD?

Normally I'd calculate Standard Distance Deviation via
$$
\hat\sigma=\text{RMSD} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\left((x_i - \bar{x})^2 + (y_i - \bar{y})^2\right)}
$$

But in my dataset, the original points are lost, I'm left with the variances. From the top of my head, I was thinking this:

$$
\hat\sigma = \sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}
$$

.. but I'm not sure if this is valid and fail to come up with a derivation for it. Does anyone have an idea? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\left((x_i - \bar{x})^2 + (y_i - \bar{y})^2\right)
 = \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\left((x_i - \bar{x})^2\right)\right)
 + \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\left((y_i - \bar{y})^2\right)\right)
$$